# Banned from chat for apparently inappropriate content?

Tags: discussion, chat, ban, appeal

Basically here is the scenario:
In the JavaScript chat room user A is talking about dummy text (keep in mind the room was pretty stagnant at the time) so I posted links to 7/8 [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) services (not the text within, just the links) and user B says stop after the first 5/6, so I finish with my links and move on. 20 minutes later I'm now banned for over an hour for these links which were not offensive; they are all dummy text generation services.

I would like to know how to appeal this other than just posting here, and if a moderator could please view - I would like to appeal this ban. I was in the middle of helping another user in the C# room when I was banned and have now abandoned him.

I just think that linking something as trivial as a lorem ipsum service should not be getting me banned.

I can link the messages saying I'm banned for, but I don't know who can see them other than me (I presume moderators, but then I also presume they can see them without me linking them).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This user has been **automatically** suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 1 hour 2 minutes.

The ban was triggered by the links simply being deleted due to flags, no one user or even a moderator was involved in suspending you.

One major problem I see is you posted them all as separate messages. Looks like spam and also moves all the other messages up the page. In the future I'd recommend that you compress all the links into a *single* message. That way you a) don't flood the chat and b) wouldn't get auto-banned if that single message was deleted. Even better, just mention the one or two that you think are the best services. No need to create an entire list of every service you can find. If they don't like those two, they can always ask you for another alternative.

While the messages weren't inappropriate in the sense of being flat-out spam or derogatory language, the way you decided to post them all was somewhat inappropriate. While not really suspension-worthy, you do have to remember that it's an automated system.

Comment: Agreed I could have written them all out in one - there is time between them (I was verifying the links). I just didn't think it to be an issue because no other users were actively talking at the time. I suppose the lurkers don't like walls.

Comment: On IRC I got banned from a channel because I posted three lines of a config file to help somebody instead of using a pastebin.  Life goes on.

Comment: and tomorrow the sun will rise for me and i'll be back in my chat rooms - still does not take the bad taste out of my mouth right now.

Comment: @rlemon you just got like 25 meta rep for this question.  be happy

Comment: yes and the ban is lifted at this point - still really irks me however. but alas, I am back!

Comment: The difference on IRC is that this is usually done by an automated bot who does that no matter what someone writes as long as he's not an op. On SO chat however it's done by humans who actively click on the "valid" button for the flag. Unfortunately way too many people do so without reading the context or handle rather harmless stuff in rooms they aren't in, also without any context...

Comment: @ThiefMaster I appreciate the feedback. :) cheers

Comment: Every WIki / youtube page you post gives a thumbprint. If you were giving back 3-5 articles about something, and wanted the thumbprint you'd be banned, versus putting all in the same message which cuts off half the link?